# watchEffect does not run when inserting new data into a list

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am making an application which the user can create projects and assign to a user, for that I am consuming an api made in go, the form sends the data to an api to persist the information and then the api returns the input data to me record the data in the array.
My form in Vue 3:

```
export default {
  setup() {
    const name = ref('');
    const description = ref('');
    const endProject = ref('');
    const user = ref(0);
    const users = ref();
    const listProjects = inject('listProjects');

    const router = useRouter();

    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/`)
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .then((response) => {
        users.value = response;
      });

    const saveProject = async () => {
      if (
        name.value === '' ||
        description.value === '' ||
        endProject.value === '' ||
        user.value === ''
      ) {
        console.log('error');
        return;
      }

      await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/projects`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: name.value,
          description: description.value,
          end_date: new Date(endProject.value.replace('-', '/')),
          user: {
            id_user: user.value,
          },
        }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .catch((error) => console.error('error:', error))
        .then((data) => {
          listProjects.value.push(data);
        });

      router.push({
        name: 'Project',
      });
    };

    return {
      name,
      description,
      endProject,
      user,
      users,
      saveProject,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

The problem happens is when I want to update the api which brings all the projects, I consider that the error occurs because the api where it registers and brings all the information are in different views, one in a form and the other in the view principal.
This is my App.vue

```
<script>
import { ref } from '@vue/reactivity';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar.vue';
import Sidebar from './components/layout/Sidebar.vue';
import { provide, watchEffect } from '@vue/runtime-core';
export default {
  components: { Navbar, Sidebar },
  setup() {
    const listProjects = ref();

    watchEffect(() => {
      console.log('bdfbdfb');
      fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/projects`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
        .then((response) => {
          listProjects.value = response;
        });
    });

    provide('listProjects', listProjects);

    return {
      listProjects,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: 1. `provide('listProjects', listProjects);` executes before the async call is finished. 2. `listProjects` is not [reactive](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html#adding-reactivity)

Comment: But this is supposed to be the way to make reactive, and it is also the way to make reactive modifications, or maybe there are other ways to do it

Comment: In the link I supplied, it explicitly discusses how to make the provide/inject reactive, and you're definitely missing that.

Comment: Don't make request calls from the component, use Vuex to assist you with these requests, it's easier to share data as well.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy The link you provided says *To add reactivity between provided and injected values, we can use a `ref` or `reactive` when providing a value.*. He is providing `ref`. So `listProjects` **is reactive**

Comment: @cosmosmulti It is not very clear what you want. Are you expecting the `watchEffect` in `App.vue` to be executed each time the POST request is finished in your form (because of `listProjects.value.push(data)`)?

Comment: @MichalLevý if it is what I am expecting that every time the view where the array is pushed is done, App.vue executes the watchEffect

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Excuse me, what I understand is that the inject should not be modified directly, but if it is a necessity we should send the function that we want to modify the variable directly, but if in this case I do not have any function, it should modify the code to perform the process in a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments:

> I am expecting that every time the view where the array is pushed is done, App.vue executes the watchEffect

Well it is not how `watchEffect` works. `watchEffect` is designed to execute some "side effects" (like fetch call) that depend on some reactive data (for example URL for fetch is created using some ID `ref`). Yours `watchEffect` does not depend on any reactive data. It only assign new value to a `listProjects` ref. (in other words, result of the function you pass to `watchEffect` does not depend on `listProjects` ref value at all)

You can debug `watchEffect` (and `watch`) using [`onTrack` option](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#watcher-debugging). See example bellow. 1st `watchEffect` **does not trigger** `onTrack` because it does not **read** any reactive data. 2nd does.

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const projects = Vue.ref([])

    Vue.watchEffect(() => {
      projects.value = []
    }, {
      onTrack(e) {
        console.log('watchEffect 1 is tracking projects')
      }
    })
    
    Vue.watchEffect(() => {
      console.log(projects.value)
    }, {
      onTrack(e) {
        console.log('watchEffect 2 is tracking projects')
      }
    })
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.1.5/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
</div>
```